# How to access a dynamic character device from userspace?

Tags: linux-kernel, mknod

The `register_chrdev()` function in kernel registers a character device:

```
int register_chrdev(unsigned  int  major,  const  char*name,
 struct file_operations*ops));
```

If `major` is `0` the kernel dynamically allocates a major number and the register function returns it.

Now, let's assume a module `foo.ko` wants to use `/dev/foo` with a dynamic major number. How does the userspace learn what major number to pass to  `mknod` to create `/dev/foo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as a character device gets registered with a dynamic major number, the corresponding information appears in `/proc/devices` and thus can be retrieved by a user-space application/script in order to create an appropriate node.

For a better example you may refer to Linux Device Drivers book (3rd edition), for instance, a script to read `/proc/devices` is shown on [this](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2) page.

Comment: And for completeness, here is a tutorial to trigger the script on module load from `udev`:
https://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/udev-rules-to-create-a-dev-node-when-inserting-a-module/